# how to manage reading a global string from a thread?

Tags: c++

I working in a simple program that reads from std input and prints the buffer when a socket message arrives.

```
std::string data;

void listen_for_messages();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::thread listenMessages(listen_for_messages);
  char c;
  while(cin.get(c)) {
     data += c;
  }
}

void listen_for_messages()
{
    while(1) {
        //receive a message from the socket
        std::cout << "\r>" << data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but data is always empty and I don't know why. Please help me!

I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0 compiler and following compile command:

```
g++ -o myprogram -pthread myprogram.cpp
```

Comment: Hint: `std::mutex`

Comment: You have no synchronisation on `data`, so the compiler probably assumes it cannot possibly ever change in `listen_for_messages`, and optimises the print to an empty string. Just a guess, but you definitely have the synchronisation bug.

Comment: I think mutex doesn't really help in this case. I no need synchronization, since one thread write the string and other read it. Is there a way to say the compiler that my string is maybe acces by different threads?